# Add tabitem to search dialogue of Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, swt, project

I am a newcomer. I am creating an Eclipse plugin project and want to add a new tab item to the existing search dialogue (that pops up when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) of Eclipse RCP. Please help me achieve it with some sample code.

Comment: Please show what you have done. Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `org.eclipse.search.searchPages` extension point to define a new search page.

As an example here is the definition for the Java search page:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.search.searchPages">
  <page
        showScopeSection="true"
        canSearchEnclosingProjects="true"
        label="%JavaSearchPage.label"
        icon="$nl$/icons/full/obj16/jsearch_obj.png"
        extensions="java:90, jav:90"
        class="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.search.JavaSearchPage"
        sizeHint="460,160"
        id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaSearchPage">
  </page>
</extension>
```

Setting up the search page and the results page is described in the Eclipse Help in the Platform Plug-in Developers Guide in the [Search Support](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fsearch_page.htm) section.